# Intermittent "SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection reset" when updating workspace from Jenkins via SVN

Tags: jenkins, svn, visualsvn-server, svnkit

I have Jenkins (2.138.3) running on a Virtual Machine.

On another PC on the same network, I have a Visual SVN Server (3.9.2).

Intermittently (maybe 25% of the time), the checkout fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to check out https://path/to/my/repository
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection reset
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/my/repository/!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:363)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1349)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:847)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.updateInternal(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:263)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.update(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:115)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:877)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:26)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:11)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:133)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:176)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:134)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1041)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1017)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:937)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:864)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.readCRLF(ChunkedInputStream.java:85)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:95)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:69)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:39)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.peekChar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
    ... 36 more
```

Anecdotally this seems to happen more often if more-than-one project is building simultaneously.

I am using Subversion 2.12.1 in Jenkins. I have tried updating from an older version of Jenkins (~6 months old) but still have this problem.

Users checking out code from the repository have not experienced these problems, however.

Comment: Not an expert in SVN / SVN Server, but did you check the server log for Jenkins connection ? Beside users checking out repository probably don't use Java but rather svn client such as Tortoise SVN.

Comment: I can find no entries in the logs of the server for any of these connections - it’s like they never happened. I contacted VisualSVN Server supported who suggested it’s likeky to be the SVN client in Jenkins that is the issue.

Comment: Your SVN client seems to be in Java. You could try to use the command line instead as a workaround. This would you require Jenkins to execute a shell command (svn checkout ...). You should also, if that is possible, try without SSL. Last but not least, you should run a ping to some IPs inside your VM to see if you don't have connection problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is produced by SVNKit which is used in Jenkins to enable SVN client capabilities. This problem seems to be specific to SVNKit because the problem does not reproduce with native Subversion clients.

To resolve the problem, add the `-Dhudson.spool-svn=true` option to Jenkins. See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1260.