# SVN E175002 - Jenkins Failed to Checkout Job

Tags: jenkins, svn, connection-reset

Jenkins keeps failing to build my job because of what appears to be an SVN error (see below; I replaced the URLs and job name for security purposes). There's been other posts about this error but none of them seem to help. Also, I noticed that the workspace is not copying all the necessary files over from the SVN repository to the workspace. In fact, it's only fetching the python virtual environment folder and a couple others and *none* of the source code files.

Sorry about formatting, this is my first post on here. Thank you for the help.

Workspace appear to be locked, so getting a fresh workspace

Cleaning local Directory.

Checking out *job* at revision '2022-09-13T10:46:48.385 -0400' --quiet

Using sole credentials Subversion Credential in realm ‘*url* Subversion Repository’

ERROR: Failed to check out *job*

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection reset
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '.../!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:363)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:859)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:915)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:133)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:176)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:185)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1073)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1049)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1022)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3317)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:75)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:39)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
    ... 31 more
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:75)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:39)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection reset
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '.../!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:363)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:859)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:915)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:133)
Retrying after 10 seconds.
```

Comment: Hi, we are facing exactly the same issue in our company. We are clueless. BTW this is a duplicate to so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996554/svn-checkout-sometimes-fails-in-jenkins it would be great to merge those.

Comment: `Connection reset` indicates that a network problem could be the cause (or the server just dropped the connection).

Comment: @m1lhaus Glad I'm not the only one, let me know if you make any discoveries.

Comment: @m1lhaus By any chance, does your script call the jenkins-cli.jar?

Comment: @Ben No, we are not using jenkins-cli.jar

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing the same behavior in our company. We are using latest VisualSVN Server v5. Whenever we checked-out huge amount of files (e.g. tons of tools), we were seeing exactly this non-informative error. Since we are Jenkins noobs, it was quite a struggle so I hope this helps.

Initially I tried suggested fix with `-Dhudson.spool-svn=true`, but that didn't help at all. Later on I went to see the [source of Jenkins SVN client](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java) to check whether this flag is still applicable and used in the source. It is. But when browsing though the docs I realized that I am setting the flag wrong in Jenkins config file. Since when I went to Jenkins console and called `System.getProperty('hudson.spool-svn')`, it returned nothing. So I copied `-Dhudson.spool-svn=true` from `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `JENKINS_ARGS`, restarted the service and since then `System.getProperty('hudson.spool-svn')` returned value `true`. But that didn't solve the issue.

After updating JDK to v17 on both master and slave I could occasionally see a different error. Something about connection timeout. After some googling we increased `http-timeout` and situation improved. I could still see this issue when running a stress test (more parallel checkouts) after few hours.

Searching though VisualSVN page I discovered [page talking about compression and caching](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00114/). We disabled the compression as recommended for fast networks (1+GB/s in our case) and increased cache size (1GB I think). Since then all stress tests passed and even multiple paralel checkouts running 9 hours finished. After enabling the compression back on, the issue reappeared.

So I am pretty sure following steps are not solution for the root cause, but rather for its effects. I believe the root cause is combination of our network and not robust Jenkins SVN client

**TL;DR**

1. Add `-Dhudson.spool-svn=true` to `JENKINS_ARGS` and to `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` under `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and restart the service
2. Verify that `hudson.spool-svn` property was set by calling `System.getProperty('hudson.spool-svn')` under `<your_jenkins_url>/script` URL. It should return `true`
3. Increase `http-timeout` on your SVN server, see e.g. https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00170/
4. In case of VisualSVN server, adjust cache size and disable compression, see https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00114/

Answer (score 0):

@m1haus I think I figured it out. The connection was timing out/resetting because it was fetching too many files from the repo. There was a lot because it was getting all of my python venv files. So I only committed the source code files to svn and not the venv files and it worked.

Comment: It is most likely linked to http timout set on jenkins server. In past days we did multiple changes on both jenkins and svn server side. I think the one helped the most was increasing http timeout on the server. Yesterday was the first time our stress test finished successfully. The stress tests was to checkout a 30GB repo in 4 paralel instances running like 8-9 hours. Now we are reverting back the changes on our test jenkins instance to find out which change specifically did it. Once I am back from vacation, I will then post official answer with complete info.

Comment: @m1lhaus Yup, that makes sense. I look forward to hearing from you when you report back